# Android MLKit - Internal error has occurred when executing Firebase ML tasks

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit

Hi I have a custom model that im using in an android app, how ever when i try to run it, an MLkitExceptions is thrown, the log output for said error is the following:

```
Internal error has occurred when executing Firebase ML tasks
```

My java code for my app looks like the following:

```java
FirebaseLocalModel localModel = new FirebaseLocalModel.Builder("local_places_recommend")
                .setAssetFilePath("recsys.tflite").build();

FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModel(localModel);



FirebaseModelOptions options = new FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
                .setLocalModelName("local_places_recommend")
                .build();

FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);

FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions =
       new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 3})
                .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 1, 34})
                .build();

float[][] input = new float[1][3];

input[0][0] = d1;
input[0][1] = d2;
input[0][2] = d3;


FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                .add(input)
                .build();
```

whenever i try to run the FirebaseModelInterpreter I get that error and nothing else.

The shape of the input tensor and output tensor are the following respectively:

```
[1 3]
<class 'numpy.float32'>
[ 1  1 34]
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Any help or insight about this issue would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

**If You are working with CameraX you may get this error.**

```
I/CameraXBasic: Internal error has occurred when executing ML Kit tasks
```

Please ensure that you close the `ImageProxy` and `image` in `analyze` function after the MLKit operation

Heere's small snippet

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

     val image:Image? = imageProxy.image

     image?.let {img->
               val iImage = InputImage
                 .fromMediaImage(img,imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
                textRecognizer.process(iImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { listener(it)}
                    .addOnFailureListener { Log.i(TAG,it.toString()) }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        image.close()
                        imageProxy.close() }
     }

}
```

Comment: How about closing the proxy if image is null?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation of Firebase :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/custom/FirebaseModelDataType

There is no type INT64, please try to write INT32 instead of FLOAT32.

```
FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions =
           new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                    .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 3})
                    .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 1, 34})// try to change FLOAT32 to Int32
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same problem because my version control changed my tflite Model and did not update my code. I had the wrong input shape for my model.
I only changed:

```
val inputOutputOptions = FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, **RightSize, RightSize**, 3))
                .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 4))
                .build()
```

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30187

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add above callback for cameraX
2. Update feature dependency to run the app by required check for below hardware feature.